# Trying to add a CSS Sub Sub Menu

Tags: css, menu, parent-child, submenu

I want you to know before I get started that I have been looking at all of the sub sub menu questions and I didn't see anything that could help the code I already have laid out. I appreciate any help at all that anybody can give me.

So, I am trying to add a sub sub menu and I thought I had figured it out, but I don't think I quite understand how to get the child combinators to work. If you could take a look at that part of the code specifically, you would be on my 'saint list.'

ETA: Oh yeah, and the problem is that the sub sub menu does not go out to the right and show up next to the parent that it is supposed to be subbing from, which is what I want it to do. I hope that makes sense.

Here is the fiddle preview - http://jsfiddle.net/BVtSC/18/

And here is the CSS:

```
/*------------------------- Header ---------------------------*/
 #header {
 background: #333 url(../images/bg-header2.png) repeat-x;
 height:184px;
 margin:15px 0 0;
}
#header div {
margin:0 auto;
padding:28px 0 0;
position:relative;
width:500px;
}
#header div ul {
height:118px;
left:10px;
list-style:none;
margin:0;
overflow:visible;
padding:0;
position:absolute;
top:10px;
float: left;
width: 500px;
}
#header div ul li:first-child {
margin:0;
}
#header div ul li {
float:left;
height:66px;
margin:0 0 0 65px;
text-align:left;
position:relative;
}
#header div ul li a {
color:#fff;
font-family:oswaldregular;
font-size:16px;
line-height:24px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
#header div ul li.selected a, #header div ul li a:hover {
color:#DD2D00;
}
#header div ul li ul {
height:1000px;
left:-99999px;
overflow:visible;
position:absolute;
top:37px;
width:115px;
float: left;
}
#header div ul li:hover ul {
left:0;
top:37px;
}
#header div ul li ul li {
background:none #343434;
border:1px solid #4f4f4f;
float:none;
height:29px;
margin:-1px 0 0;
padding:0 12px;
position:relative;
width:auto;
z-index:1000;
}
#header div ul li ul li:hover {
background:none #DD2D00;
}
#header div ul li ul li:hover {
left:0;
top:0;
}
#header div ul li ul li a {
color:#ffffff!important;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
line-height:28px;
text-transform:none;
}
#header div ul li ul li.selected a, #header div ul li ul li a:hover {
color:#fff!important;
}
#header div ul li ul li ul {
height:1000px;
right:-99999px;
overflow:visible;
position:absolute;
top:37px;
width:115px;
float: right;
}
#header div ul li ul li:hover ul {
left:0;
top:37px;
}
#header div ul li ul li ul li {
background:none #343434;
border:1px solid #4f4f4f;
float:none;
height:29px;
margin:-1px 0 0;
padding:0 12px;
position:relative;
width:auto;
z-index:1000;
}
#header div ul li ul li ul li:hover {
background:none #DD2D00;
}
#header div ul li ul li ul li:hover {
left:0;
top:0;
}
#header div ul li ul li ul li a {
color:#ffffff!important;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
line-height:28px;
text-transform:none;
}
#header div ul li ul li ul li.selected a, #header div ul li ul li ul li a:hover {
color:#fff!important;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="header">
<div>   

    <ul>
        <li>    <a href="index.html">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li>    <a href="about.html">About</a>

        </li>

        <li class="selected">   <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>

            <ul>
                <li>    <a href="fantasy.html">Fantasy</a>

                </li>
                <li>    <a href="makeup.html">Makeup</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="glamour.html">Glamour Makeup</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="sfxmakeup.html">Special Effects Makeup</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>    <a href="boudoir.html">Boudoir</a>

                </li>
                <li>    <a href="babykids.html">Baby & Kids</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="baby.html">Baby</li>
                        <li><a href="baby.html">Kids</li>  </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="family.html">Family</a>

                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="couples.html">Couples</li>
                        <li><a href="mombaby.html">Mother/Baby</li>
                        <li><a href="momchild.html">Mother/Child</li>
                        <li><a href="fatherchild.html">Father/Child</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="pets.html">Pets</a>

                                </li>
                                <li>    <a href="portrait.html">Portrait</a>

                                </li>
                                    </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li>    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Again, any help at all would do wonders. Thank you for your consideration. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or you can use this which is a simple example of nested menu.(unlimited). [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nS5P5)
you should just adjust its size and color.

HTML

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">sub item1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sub item2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sub item3</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">sub sub item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">sub sub item 2</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">sub sub sub item1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">sub sub sub item2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">sub sub sub item3</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="">yes why not?</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">you can still continue</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">if you want</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">you can try.(-;</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="">sub sub sub item4</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">sub sub item 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">sub item4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">item3</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul.menu{
    position:relative;
}


ul.menu li{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid;
}

ul.menu > li{
    float:left;
    padding:10px 45px;
}

ul.menu > li li{
    padding:7px;
}

ul.menu , ul.menu ul{
    list-style:none;
    padding:5px;
    margin:0;
    overflow:visible;
}

ul.menu li:hover > ul{
    display:block;
}

ul.menu ul{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:-6px;
    top:37px;
    width:160px;
}

ul.menu ul:hover{
    display:block;
}

ul.menu ul ul{
    left:158px;
    top:0;
}
```

Comment: Yay!!!! I am giving you a huge virtual hug. You helped me figure out the problem. I can't tell you how much I appreciate your help. I have given you reputation on everything and accepted your answer. You have also been declared a saint in the church of AceofHearts!

Answer (score 3):

three things can help you.
first using '>' in css selectors.
 second using this

```
ul ul{
    display:none;
}
ul > li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
}
```

that cause a ul block being displayed when you hover on its '< li >' parent.
and third one is using css positions to adjust submenus position.like this

```
#header > ul{
    position:relative;
}
li{
    position:relative;
}
ul ul{
    position:absolute;
    left:120px;
    top:0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. The display:none & display:block worked perfectly, but I cannot figure out how to get it to go out to the right. No matter what I do, it stays behind the parent sub menu. Here is the link again http://jsfiddle.net/BVtSC/47/. If you have it in you to look and see what I am doing wrong, I would really be in your debt. I am just really stuck. I tried your solution at the bottom with the positions but it messed up the formatting completely. Thanks again for your help so far and your possible further help. :)

Comment: your welcome.everyone supports each others in here one with answering and one with voting up the answers and useful comments.(:.I had searched in my codes to find a similar code to post here but I don't find anything.I will try to find or write it but it will be late for you I think.so some advice. try to write your code from beginning and try to use li > ul instead of li ul.and just use li ul (for often general things).and also try to understand each part of your code is doing what and is for what.(-:

Comment: Thank you so much imsiso. I agree with what you said at the bottom about understanding each part of the code and I have definitely been trying to do that. Stack overflow does wonders for my code education. If you can find or write code to help with my problem and it won't be too much trouble, it is never too late for me. Ever. :) Thank you for how much you help people. I finally got enough reputation today to vote up answers and I definitely voted yours up. :)